# Link to marker in custom embeded google map

Tags: google-maps, iframe

I have an embedded custom google map with custom markers (uses iframe) on a webpage. Is there a way I can center on a specific marker in this EMBEDDED MAP depending on GET variables passed in the link?
Any help is appreciated! Thanks!

Comment: You can add the optional center parameter to set your map center where the marker is. Here's more [**detail**](https://developers.google.com/maps/documentation/embed/guide#optional_parameters)

Comment: Exaclty what I was looking for! Thanks!